# How to catch app link using uni_links in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Inside **AndroidManifest.xml** I have configured the following intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
            <data
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When I click on a URL from my website it shows me to open the link using my app.

Here my home page dart code:

```
    bool initialURILinkHandled = false;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Uri? initialURI;
  Uri? currentURI;
  Object? err;
  StreamSubscription? streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initURIHandler();
    incomingLinkHandler();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initURIHandler() async {
    if (!initialURILinkHandled) {
      initialURILinkHandled = true;
      try {
        final initialURITemp = await getInitialUri();
        if (initialURI != null) {
          debugPrint("Initial URI received $initialURITemp");
          if (!mounted) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            initialURI = initialURITemp;
          });
        } else {
          debugPrint("Null Initial URI received");
        }
      } on PlatformException {
        debugPrint("Failed to receive initial uri");
      } on FormatException catch (error) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        debugPrint('Malformed Initial URI received');
        setState(() => err = error);
      }
    }
  }

  void incomingLinkHandler() {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      streamSubscription = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        debugPrint('Received URI: $uri');
        setState(() {
          currentURI = uri;
          err = null;
        });
      }, onError: (Object error) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        debugPrint('Error occurred: $error');
        setState(() {
          currentURI = null;
          if (error is FormatException) {
            err = error;
          } else {
            err = null;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final queryParams = currentURI?.queryParametersAll.entries.toList();

    //I have deleted the code here for simplicity
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

I am looking at the console but the initial URL is always null and no received URLs are printed out in the console.

So, how can I catch the clicked HTTPS URL so I can navigate the user to a specific route depending on that URL?